Reflux under inert conditions
If a procedure calls for reflux under inert conditions, is it alright if I let nitrogen as protective gas run through the condenser for about 15 minutes, and then attach it to the flask with pre-stirred reactants under nitrogen counterflow?
Will it be enough to get rid of the oxygen in the condenser?

That sounds more than sufficient

Even though I did not cycle it? Like put it under vacuum, add nitrogen etc., I just flooded it

What kind of reaction do you want to do? This decides how strict you need to be. For most purposes, what you describe may suffice, but in some cases not.

@Mäßige  as Snijderfrey says the reaction plays a part here. What air-sensitive materials are you using? in the reactions I ran using organolithiums or Pd catalysts just flushing was mostly sufficient

It depends on the reaction. Nitrogen is not an inert gas, in itself -- for example, it reacts with alkali metals. What reaction?
